# How to inject a middleware script to each page in a Next.js web project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm joining a new team using Next.js -- the principal UI programmer has recently left and I am a first-time react and javascript user. I'd like to add a floating live chat support icon (provided by a SaSS middleware), which has asks that we add the following integration:

```
<script>
      (function(d,t) {
        var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src=BASE_URL+"/packs/js/sdk.js";
        g.defer = true;
        g.async = true;
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
        g.onload=function(){
          window.chatSDK.run({
            token: '...',
            baseUrl: BASE_URL
          })
        }
      })(document,"script");
    </script>
```

Where would be the best place to inject such a thing into a Next project? We have a structure that looks like:

```
web/
 MyApp/
   pages/
      login.tsk
      home.tsk
      ...
```

where each page has the structure

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <MyLayout
      header={<MyHeader selectedKeys={["security"]} />}
      content={<MyPageDetails />}
      footer={<MyFooter />}
    />
  );
}
```

and MyLayout is some kind of dynamic something something, returning a React.ComponentType:

```
export default function dynamic<P = {}>(dynamicOptions: DynamicOptions<P> | Loader<P>, options?: DynamicOptions<P>): React.ComponentType<P>;
```

Likely... I want to apply the change to all pages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's document file **_document.js** that you can overwrite and put you custom JS codes in head or body. which will load on every page.

./pages/_document.js

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          // here's where you put your script
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5JH6SSG');
                  `,
            }}
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

more on doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware there's one way. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

`Component` should switch to your page component in every page route.

If i remember correctly, you can do

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <div>
      Do whatever i want
      <Component {...pageProps} {...sendWhateverIwant} />
    </div>
  )
}
```